# Is there a name for the **writing** tic/technique in which the **writer** inserts an aside beginning with "well"?

Tags: style

Is there a name for this writing tic/technique (which I find very annoying, by the way):

*Please note: these examples are in the form of dialogue which belies the context in which my question was meant to be placed. I've therefore added additional examples at the bottom of this post that are actual writing samples (slightly modified to protect the author's identity) that contain this tic/technique.*

> > “I ate an omelette that was, well, made of eggs.”
> >
> > “The sun rose and, well, I woke up.”
> >
> > “These sentences are, well, quite frankly annoying.”

Thank you

---

edit: as it says in the question, I'm asking about writing, not speaking. Not sure why multiple people are confusing that point.

---

edit 2:

Examples of what I mean, not in dialogue form:

e.g.
Rather than fire back sarcastically at what I find to be unsuccessfully pedantic comments, I choose to, well, accept the input and try to clarify my question.

e.g.
I was writing an article yesterday that was, well, about something I wished to discuss!

e.g.
This essay which I am writing is, well, a statement of my personal opinions.

Comment: I'm not sure why you find this annoying. In fiction, you may feel that this is necessary, especially if you are introducing a complex issue that the speaker is trying to convey more simply: __Dr  Smith said to his patient, "The treatment of Hepatitis C has improved leaps and bounds since we discovered this new medicine that works on the, um, virus's structure.__ The doctor knows the technical terms but needs to figure out a better way to communicate it.

Comment: Related on ELU:  [Is Valley Girl speak “like”, entering the language?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1531/161), also [Is there a word for “umming”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/34249/161)

Comment: @StuW - it's about **WRITING** not speaking.

Comment: I think people are addressing your question in terms of spoken English for a very good reason: The examples you give are all dialogue, so of course the answers will follow suit. If this is unacceptable to you, then I don't understand what your question is asking. (Yes, the downvote is mine.)

Comment: @NeilFein obviously, the fault is mine since, despite whatever objections I have, it's seen as a question about dialogue by this site's readers. That is  therefore what it is. In that light, I've added examples to emphasize the *intended* nature of my question. At the same time, I see now that many commenters here see writing from the viewpoint of a storyteller, as opposed to that of an analyst or essayist. I think these things that I find annoying are much more appropriate for fiction, especially written dialogue, than analysis. Of course, they're also quite acceptable when actually speaking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technical term is 'filler'. A filler is used to give the speaker time to think. Other fillers include 'er', 'um', 'okay', 'ah' and 'like'.

Comment: I'm talking about people writing not speaking.

Comment: Well, if you're writing, you can use a filler to, um, simulate natural speech patterns.

Comment: @Karen yes, indeed!

Comment: Answer accepted as *conversation* filler, *“to give the speaker time to think,”* in spoken or written dialogue. The reason I've found fillers annoying is that I find them in analytical texts, where they arguably have no place.

Comment: Unless you're trying to write dialogue these sort of words should be avoided. Children sometimes do it because they don't understand the differences between spoken and written language.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, I'd say it's an interjection. In this case, a verbalized pause while the speaker collects their thoughts.

Generally, I'd say avoid it unless you're developing a hesitant or insecure character.